# Where can I find a complete list of types of dates (and date APIs) in modern C++ & Win32?

Tags: c++, date, winapi, time, c++-winrt

I'm doing some date/time manipulation (*shudders*, thinking about [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca)), and I want to know what basic APIs I have access to, working in modern C++/WinRT and Win32.

**What types and APIs exist on the system APIs or in the standard library for date & time manipulation?**

I know about a few things:

- [SYSTEMTIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/system-time) (for system time and [local time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/local-time))
- [FILETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times)
- [MS-DOS time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/ms-dos-date-and-time) (see [Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/time) (MSDN) for info and [Time functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/time-functions) (MSDN) for all of the above and more; see also [National Language Support - Date and Calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/date-and-calendar) (MSDN))
- [winrt::DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.datetime?view=winrt-22621), which actually specializes `std::chrono::time_point` in C++/WinRT, but has different semantics in other languages like C++/CX
- [winrt::Calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.calendar?view=winrt-22621) and [winrt::DateTimeFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter?view=winrt-22621) for globalized dates
- (C++11, augmented in C++20) [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono), based on HowardHinnant's [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library (compatible with earlier C++)
- [VT_DATE](https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/16/erics-complete-guide-to-vt_date/) (via Simon Mourier)
- and plenty more if you're using .NET instead

Plus I have some reference guides:

- [Time formatting and time zones in Win32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/time-formatting-and-time-zones-in-win32) (MSDN)
- [Globalization - World calendars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/calendar-differences) (MSDN)
- [Date & time in Windows API](https://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/datetime/) (ZetCode)
- [Date and Time in C++](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3049/Date-and-Time-in-C) (CodeProject)

But I'd love to have a complete, authoritative list.

Comment: The `std::chrono` library has been available in C++ since C++11. C++20 simply added additional features to it.

Comment: There's also automation date type (VT_DATE) which stores dates as a double floating point number https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/16/erics-complete-guide-to-vt_date/ with various utility (SystemTimeToVariantTime, VarDateFromXXX)

Comment: There's no point in searching more. You already have more that you 'd need.

Comment: I wonder which practical problem an exhaustive list would solve. Given that date and time types apparently get invented all the time, that list won't stay exhaustive for very long anyway.

Comment: If C++20 std::chrono can't solve it, let me know.  I'll try to fix that if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, there is no complete list online, but the list in the question is a fair start.